# JSON: How to iterate json object to get the result in key=value format when key is unknown?

Tags: jquery, json

I am using jquery $.post() method to retrive from database form input records for the inputs provided by user to form. My json object coming is this:

```
[{"ttfdgdf":"sdafsdf"},
{"number":"34243"},
{"gfgfgrg":"vvsvd"},
{"bfghngfh":"453467"},
{"mvbmnbm":"vgdfgvdfg"},
{"cb":"on"},
{"radio":"on"},
{"lkl":"f231"},
{"lklkl":"453243"}]
```

But i don't know how to iterate this as the entry is dynamic & keys are not fixed(key will be given dynamically by user who is building the form).

Comment: you need to have a 2 level iteration... one for the list another for the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iterate thru your data using [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, as:

```
var data = [{"ttfdgdf":"sdafsdf"},
{"number":"34243"},
{"gfgfgrg":"vvsvd"},
{"bfghngfh":"453467"},
{"mvbmnbm":"vgdfgvdfg"},
{"cb":"on"},
{"radio":"on"},
{"lkl":"f231"},
{"lklkl":"453243"}];

//iterate thru array of objects using for loop
for(var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    //use for..in loop to iterate thru your object
    for(var key in data[i]) {
        console.log( key + "=" + data[i][key] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is the simple one

Answer (score 0):

You first need to loop through the indexed array at the top. you can do this with a simple for loop.

After that, you need a property loop. with that you loop through indexed names/property names. There is only one caveat with that and that is you need a second test to see if its an "own" property or an inhereted prototype property(for example indexOf, toString, length, etc...)

You kinda end up with this construct. Fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/5t93n7t2/

```
var arr = [{"ttfdgdf":"sdafsdf"},
{"number":"34243"},
{"gfgfgrg":"vvsvd"},
{"bfghngfh":"453467"},
{"mvbmnbm":"vgdfgvdfg"},
{"cb":"on"},
{"radio":"on"},
{"lkl":"f231"},
{"lklkl":"453243"}];

for(var c=0;c<arr.length;c++) {
    for(var key in arr[c]) {
        if(arr[c].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            document.getElementById('contents').innerHTML+= "<BR/>Key="+key+", Value="+arr[c][key];
        }
    }
}
```